# How to hide wsdl information on WCF?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I thought that deleting of endpoint with 'IMetadataExchange' is enough. I did that but wsdl file is still generated...

How to hide wsdl information on WCF?

P.S. Probably my question is not valid (I don't understand WCF too deep), so please correct me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your service's behavior configuration most probably contains:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

Remove `serviceMetadata` behavior from your service configuration or turn its `httpGetEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like that helps.